# SharePoint Server Full

Tags: sharepoint-server

My sharepoint server is full, can anyone please teach me how do I expand the server? Can any one please help me?
I will be very very grateful!

I have a Server that I used it for SharePoint.. However, the server is quite full now.. Can anyone recommend me any cost saving features that I could use? 
I understand shrinking the SharePoint database is one of them... 
How do I add some more hard drive in the server? or is there anything like it? 
pleawe share knowledge with me.

Comment: What do you mean with full?

Comment: My Server is full... I need to possibly free up some space or I'll need to have another sharepoint environment.....

Comment: if it is Physical server then add new hard drive and extend the drive/partition, in which database resides, from Disk Management..... and  If it is a VM then mount more storage to the server from the Host server and Extend the Database drive/partition from Disk Management

Comment: Full is a general description? which is full the hard disk or database? could you mention what's the current topology of your farm (how many servers you have) and some details to make your quest clear and open it back?!

Comment: Hi cjs , my physical server are full... do I add new hard drive and extend the drive/partition as per normal? a friend told me that I couldn't just add nother hard drive as I have RAID to think about... 
I have no idea >.<

Comment: Is your environment hosted on the cloud? you got two take both scenarios and add the costs up basically.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SQL server databases (SharePoint) full, then you need to use shrink 
[How to shrink SQL / SharePoint database](https://www.satheesh.net/2011/04/05/how-to-shrink-sql-sharepoint-database-log-files/)

SharePoint Config database logs are one thing to keep an eye on since they do have a tendency to grow. If you don’t perform a full farm backup usually the log doesn’t get emptied and it just keeps bloating.

If you’re running SQL Server Express with default installation, you can find the files in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data

Comment: What i'm asking, is:
1) the sharepoint here --> sharepoint.mycompany.com is full
2) Should I try to expand it? or make another sharepoint environment?
3) I want to save cost...

Comment: Or do I need to move it to SharePoint Online?